# My Production is frequently facing out of the memory Issue

Tags: php, laravel, apache, amazon-ec2, server

On my production server, I'm frequently facing memory problem. apache error log frequently logging this error.

```
856685.751702] Out of memory: Kill process 29946 (httpd) score 12 or sacrifice child
[856685.757737] Killed process 29946 (httpd) total-vm:585720kB, anon-rss:25324kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:72kB
```

In the Laravel Log file, I have this error is logging frequently.

```
[2021-01-29 07:10:45] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Out of memory (allocated 14680064) (tried to allocate 1052672 bytes) in /var/www/html/instacutportal/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Stream.php:228
Stack trace:
```

I have some questions.

1. Suppose somebody is using the system, they're logged in and doing stuff. When they're done, they close the browser tab without logging out. How does the server respond and release resources? Dose laravel handles it by itself?
2. I have a file uploading feature where users can upload 200+ images, I'm storing it on an S3 bucket. The images are pass through the application server. dose there is some stage of an upload process where images or (parts of them at least) are stays in application server memory. Which seemed like it might be relevant for out of memory errors. in nutshell dose it store locally first?

Comment: laravel process get kill every request you can check here https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/eaf7289523b0730b3d0c5a7146ab0f078019a987/public/index.php#L55

Answer (score 2):

Take a careful look at the error message:

`Out of memory (allocated 14680064) (tried to allocate 1052672 bytes) in /var/www/html/instacutportal/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Stream.php:228`

PHP is trying to allocate 1052672 bytes of memory on line 228 in the file /var/www/html/instacutportal/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Stream.php, which is more than it is allowed to allocate.

This file is part of the guzzle library. Somewhere in your application you are interacting with guzzle in a way which exceeds your PHP memory_limit setting. The full stack trace in the error should contain the file and line this is happening on, but this likely relates to your second question. Depending on how you upload the images, it likely loads them in full in locally memory before uploading them.

There are a few ways you could approach solving this.

1. increase the php memory_limit setting.
2. look into chunking the data as you read it from the user submission.
3. change the ui to upload and fully process the images one at a time.

Comment: 1. memory_limit is set to 256M, I think that's enough.

2. didn't get this point can you please explain me in brief?

3. In the Image uploading process user can select multiple images but not every image will upload at the same time. The Upload image API will be called for each image so only one image will be got processed at a time. And also I have to mention that I am reducing the size of the image before it get uploaded but this resizing process is happening on angular side(FE side) dose it affect the server?

Comment: When the user uploads the file, the laravel application is loading the file into memory in order to process it. This means that the memory_limit is effectively limiting the file size. Chunking the image upload is likely the best solution. This means your angular front end will need to process the image and break it into chunks/pieces of a predefined size, and send each of those to the server one at a time. The server will then need to process them one at a time, appending them to the file being written. There are likely third party packages ready to help with this in both laravel and angular.

Comment: Chunking is a common practice, especially for processing video files. It's worth googling around for more information and ideas specific to technology and use case you are working with.

Comment: Thanks, James Now I got your point. the concept you are talking about is similar to the stream and buffer concept.